# How are the glyph hack bonuses calculated?

Tags: ingress

Did anyone come across a formula for the calculation of the glyph hacks? There seem to be many questions and attempts at it but I couldn't find any definite answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The formulas in [this post on glyph hacking](http://fevgames.net/ingress/ingress-guide/actions/glyph-hack/) are based on extensive field testing.

Relevant part from the post:

---

```
+------------+--------------------+------------+
| Portal lvl | Perfect hack bonus | Time limit |
+------------+--------------------+------------+
|          1 |               +28% |        20s |
|          2 |               +40% |        20s |
|          3 |               +55% |        20s |
|          4 |               +55% |        19s |
|          5 |               +55% |        18s |
|          6 |               +80% |        17s |
|          7 |               +80% |        16s |
|          8 |              +112% |        15s |
+------------+--------------------+------------+
```

Hack bonus:


*B<sub>hack</sub>* = 10 × *G<sub>correct</sub>* + *P* × *B<sub>perfect</sub>*

Speed bonus:


*B<sub>speed</sub>* = *P* × ⌊100 × *T<sub>left</sub>* ÷ *T<sub>limit</sub>*⌋

AP:


*AP<sub>base</sub>* = 50 × *G<sub>correct</sub>*

*AP<sub>bonus</sub>* = 20 × *P* × 2<sup>0.5×*G<sub>correct</sub>*</sup>

*AP* = *AP<sub>base</sub>* + *AP<sub>bonus</sub>* + *B<sub>speed</sub>*

where:

- *P* is 1 if all glyphs were drawn correctly and 0 otherwise (*P* = ⌊*G<sub>correct</sub> ÷* *G<sub>total</sub>*⌋),
- *B<sub>hack</sub>* is the hacking bonus,
- *G<sub>correct</sub>* is the number of glyphs you got correct,
- *G<sub>total</sub>* is the total number of glyphs in the sequence,
- *B<sub>perfect</sub>* is the perfect hack bonus corresponding to the number of glyphs in the sequence, as shown in the table above,
- *B<sub>speed</sub>* is the speed bonus,
- *T<sub>left</sub>* is the time remaining on the clock,
- *T<sub>limit</sub>* is the total time you were given to draw the sequence, as shown in the table above,
- *AP<sub>base</sub>* is the amount of AP earned for correctly-drawn glyphs,
- *AP<sub>bonus</sub>* is bonus AP earned for drawing all glyphs correctly,
- *AP* is the total amount of AP earned from the glyph hack. (Note: Does not include AP from hacking enemy portals.)

Example: Suppose you perform a perfect glyph hack on a L7 portal with 5 seconds left. Your hacking bonus would be 10% × 4 + 1 × 80% = **120%** (4 correct glyphs and perfect hack bonus). Your speed bonus would be 1 × ⌊100 × 5 ÷ 16⌋ = **31%** (5 out of 16 seconds left). Finally, you would earn **8** glyph hacking points and 50 × 4 + 20 × 1 × 2<sup>0.5×4</sup> + 31 = **311 AP**.

Comment: I'm a bit worried that basicly the entire answer is in a picture. It's not as risky as a link- or video-only answer, but if the picutre ever gets taken down, the answer will be useless. It would benefit the answer's longevity to write out at least the text portion of it. I belive StackExchange has some support for mathematic notation. It's used a lot on mathematics oriented SE-sites.

Comment: While hacking enemy portal we get more AP near about 401

Comment: That's because just hacking an enemy portal gives you +100 ap, then the glyphs add in.

Comment: Neat writeup to calculate the AP bonus.  What I have a question on (or am maybe missing in the explanation) is how the item bonus ends up being calculated.  E.g. I do a perfect 4 glyph hack and the UI tells me I get 120% for that, then a 68% speed bonus.  Does this mean I get 188% more items?